# Close React Modal With Submit

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

Hello there I'm trying to figure out how to close this modal and submit a new item at the same time... right now it's only doing one or the other. If I put `<button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Submit</button>` at the bottom there it wont submit the information in the form and if I take away `{this.handleCloseModal}` then it'll add the item but I have to refresh to close the modal.

```js
class AddItem extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
   showModal: false
  };

  this.handleOpenModal = this.handleOpenModal.bind(this);
     this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
   }
  
    handleOpenModal () {
     this.setState({ showModal: true });
   }
  
    handleCloseModal () {
     this.setState({ showModal: false });
   }


 render() {
  return(
  <div>
  <button onClick={this.handleOpenModal}>Add Item</button>
  <ReactModal isOpen={this.state.showModal}>
  <form 
   onSubmit={(event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const input = {
     name: event.target.itemName.value,
     price: event.target.itemPrice.value,
     description: event.target.itemDescription.value, 
     userEmail: this.props.currentUser.email
   }

    this.props.dispatch(saveItem(input))
  
    event.target.itemName.value = ''
    event.target.itemPrice.value = ''
    event.target.itemDescription.value = ''
  
   }}>
    <label>
     Item Name:
     <br />
     <input type="text" name="itemName" validate={[required, nonEmpty]} />
    </label>
    <br />
    <label>
     Price:
     <br />
     <input type="text" name="itemPrice" validate={[required, nonEmpty]} />
    </label>
    <br />
    
    <br />
    <label>
    Description:
     <br />
     <textarea type="text" name="itemDescription" validate={[required, nonEmpty]} />
    </label>
    <br />
    <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Submit</button>
   </form>
   </ReactModal>
   </div>
  )
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    currentUser: state.auth.currentUser
});
 
 export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(AddItem));
```

Comment: Why dont just add this.handleCloseModal at the bottom of onSubmit after you dispatched the action?

Comment: @Roy.B I tried that and got this error:
Line 52:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function handler for submitting the form, and then closing the modal at the end.

```
handleOnSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const input = {
        name: event.target.itemName.value,
        price: event.target.itemPrice.value,
        description: event.target.itemDescription.value, 
        userEmail: this.props.currentUser.email
    }

    this.props.dispatch(saveItem(input))

    event.target.itemName.value = ''
    event.target.itemPrice.value = ''
    event.target.itemDescription.value = ''

    this.handleCloseModal(); <--- you can place it right here
}
```

The button would be using to trigger the onSubmit function passed to your form:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
.
.
.
</form>

// Here the button will use the form onSubmit by default
// Hence, handleOnSubmit will be called
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Don't forget to bind handleOnSubmit

Comment: Perfect! My problem was I wasn't calling as a function, just putting this.handleCloseModal

Comment: @Ally consider using mapDispatchToProps, it will keep you organized so you can avoid this cases in the future by attaching dispatch to all your actions.